# Modify Avada Wordpress theme template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am making changes to a Wordpress site which uses the Avada Wordpress theme.

The page I want to change uses the 100% width template, as do many other pages.

I need to add markup in a place that doesn't allow me to do so via the page editor.

So it looks like I need to change the template.

I know I should make a child theme, but then should I create a new template (code duplication), or should I check the page inside the template, or is there a better way (some kind of refactoring?).?

Comment: depends on the parent theme, but wp will automatically look for templates in the child theme first so thats definitely the wp way...